# HTML Canvas align DIV at bottom right-hand corner

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a Canvas and want to add a Div/Button in the bottom right-hand corner relative to Canvas. My current code looks as follows:

```css
#container {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 96%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 300px;
}

#viewer {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
}

#button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

canvas {
    border: 3px solid black; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="viewer">
        <canvas></canvas>
        <div id="button" onclick="myFunction();"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But so far I couldn't manage to find a proper solution for this. It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: `position:relative` on viewer?

Comment: No, I already tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: in all the cases you need `position:relative` somewhere or it's like you are using position;fxied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
I recommand you checking out this article: [CSS Layout - The position Property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
#container{
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 96%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 300px;
}

#viewer{
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

#button{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

canvas{
    border: 3px solid black; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="viewer">
       <canvas></canvas>
       <div id="button" onclick="myFunction();"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Temani was right — this puts the button at the bottom right of the canvas, is this not what you wanted?

```css
#container{
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 96%;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: blue;
 height: 300px;
}

#viewer{
 width: 40%;
 background-color: red;
 height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#button{
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 background-color: green;
 position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

canvas{
border: 3px solid black; 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="viewer">
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="button" onclick="myFunction();"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like *Temani Afif* said.

```
position:relative
```

on **#viewer** worked for me.